# Transclude on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

im trying to repeat a directive inside the directive so i can have a template on each of directive but the problem is i can only show the first entry when using **ng-transclude**

Here is what i've done so far

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <test-collector>
            <test-data xx-value="Mouse" xx-href="https://fb.com" />
            <test-data xx-value="Keyboard" xx-href="https://goo.gl" />
        </test-collector>        
    </div>
</div>
```

and for the controller

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);

app.directive("testCollector", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,  
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope) {

        },
        template: '<div>' +
                        '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                   '</div>'
    }
});

app.directive("testData", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require: '^testCollector',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            xxValue: '@',
            xxHref: "@"
        },
        template: '<a href="{{xxHref}}">{{xxValue}}</a>'
    }
});
```

i only get **Mouse**

i prepared a fiddle to see it in action [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yk3f8kvo/1/)

any help please.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're messing with your directive `<test-data>` tag. You haven't close the `test-data`. You gave self closing tag to `test-data` element like as `<test-data />`.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <test-collector>
            <test-data xx-value="Mouse" xx-href="https://fb.com"></test-data>
            <test-data xx-value="Keyboard" xx-href="https://goo.gl"></test-data>
        </test-collector>        
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n56qgb38/2/)

Comment: Hi @pankajparkar can i add another question? just related to this anyway, my question is how to add the <test-data> upon click on button? here is some sample http://jsfiddle.net/yk3f8kvo/7/

Comment: after adding question let me know. I'll some time on it.

Comment: here it is @pankajparkar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019280/adding-directive-inside-the-directive-programatically

Comment: I solved it.check answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019280/adding-directive-inside-the-directive-programatically/28019431#28019431