# Adding directive inside the directive programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-compile

I want to append another instance of my directive into the parent directive but i can't use $apply to recompile my directive.

I think i miss something here somewhere :)

**My HTML Code**

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <input ng-model="NewData" />
        <button ng-click="AddNewData($event)">Add New</button>
        <br /><br />
        <div test-collector="testColScope" id="testCol">
            <div test-data="" xx-value="Mouse" xx-href="https://fb.com"></div>
            <div test-data="" xx-value="Keyboard" xx-href="https://goo.gl"></div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

**My JavaScript Code**

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){   

    $scope.AddNewData = function($event){

        // i also want to access this but it shows undefined
      console.log("test-collector", $scope.testColScope);

      var div = $('<div></div>')
        .attr(
            {
                "test-data":"",
                "xx-value":$scope.NewData,
                "xx-href":"http://p.com"
            });       

        //$scope.$apply(function(){
            $('#testCol').append(div);  
        //});        
    };
}]);

app.directive("testCollector", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {

        },
        transclude: true,  
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope);
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);
            scope[attrs.testCollector] = {
                Enteng : 'Dagpin'
            };
        },
        template: '<div>' +
                        '<ul><div ng-transclude></div></ul>' +
                   '</div>'
    }
});

app.directive("testData", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: '^testCollector',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            xxValue: '@',
            xxHref: "@"
        },
        template: '<li><a href="{{xxHref}}">{{xxValue}}</a></li>'
    }
});
```

Here is [Fiddle with Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/yk3f8kvo/7/)

Comment: You are not able to access the values of the testCollector from TestCtrl because test collector defines a new scope. Values on scopes are not propagated up.

Comment: is there any way to say like scope.$parent[attrs.testCollector] = {
                Enteng : 'Dagpin'
            }; ?

Comment: You could but it would just work if you removed the child scope on the directive. Just don't define `scope: {}` in the testCollector directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand angular new element has been inserted you need to first compile that element using `$compile` service like `$compile(div)($scope)` then only you can append that element in Angular DOM.

And you directive has already rendered on html, so the div structure is changed.

instead of doing $('#testCol') use `angular.element('#testCol ul div')`

Here is [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk3f8kvo/8/)

**Update 1**

As per @enzey DOM manipulation should not be done inside controller. It should be done inside directive. That's why @Vincent & I made the changes in fiddle.
DOM manipulation logic has been moved to inside directive.

Here is [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk3f8kvo/11/)

Comment: Doing DOM manipulation withing a controller is an Angular bad practice. That is the old JavaScript way that is completely not needed when using Angular as it is intended.

Comment: @Enzey you mean to say for single, ng-click only i need to create a directive? I'm using angular.element which is safe

Comment: You should be adding an ng-click as part of the HTML initially. If not and your are adding it programmatically then, yes, you would use a directive.

Comment: so maybe i would just expose an AddNewData from $scope.testColScope which is my directive (parent) right? then just compile it there

Comment: @VincentDagpin looks cool..only change `$('<div></div>')` to `angular.element`.. avoid use of Jquery $ to manipulate angular DOM element

Comment: @Enzey Please verify the fiddle. and give suggetion if any.Thanks.

Comment: @VincentDagpin Mark the answer as correct, if it does solved your problem. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting DOM manipulation from within a controller. Changing the DOM is the purpose of directives. That is the first thing you need to address.

As for adding a directive to a child element in DOM you just need to use the compile function of a directive.

```
Module.directive('name', function () {
    return {
        compile: function ($element, $attrs) {
            \\ here
        }
    }
}
```